# Horizontal alignment on bmatrix environment

Tags: matrices, alignment, horizontal

I'm writing a report that contains a lot of matrices. At some point in the text, I've written the following code

EDIT: as I've been told, I'll upload a code that better represents the problem I'm having, including the structure configuration.

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite} % bibtex

\input{structure}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ASSIGNMENT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{Problem with matrix alignment}
\author{Not Sure \\ \texttt{not.sure@email.com} \\ Number: \texttt{123456} }
\date{25th-Sep-2018}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Equation (\ref{eqn:volt_hf_theta_esteemed}) is not aligned.

\begin{equation} \label{eqn:volt_hf_theta_esteemed}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        u_{dh}^{\hat{r}} \\
        u_{qh}^{\hat{r}}
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        j\omega_h \left(L_{avg} + \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\right) & j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\sin(2\theta_\epsilon) \\
        j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\sin(2\theta_\epsilon) & j\omega_h \left(L_{avg} - \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\right)
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        i_{dsh}^{\hat{r}} \\
        i_{qsh}^{\hat{r}}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation} % fix horiziontal alignment

\end{document}
```

The "\input{structure}" thing is the following template

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Lachaise Assignment
% Structure Specification File
% Version 1.0 (26/6/2018)
%
% This template originates from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Authors:
% Marion Lachaise & François Févotte
% Vel (vel@LaTeXTemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,stmaryrd,amssymb,tabstackengine} % Math packages

\usepackage{enumerate} % Custom item numbers for enumerations

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e} % Algorithms

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} % Allows defining custom boxed/framed environments

\usepackage{listings} % File listings, with syntax highlighting
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily, % Typeset listings in monospace font
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DOCUMENT MARGINS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{geometry} % Required for adjusting page dimensions and margins

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Paper size, change to letterpaper for US letter size
    top=2.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=3cm, % Bottom margin
    left=2.5cm, % Left margin
    right=2.5cm, % Right margin
    headheight=14pt, % Header height
    footskip=1.5cm, % Space from the bottom margin to the baseline of the footer
    headsep=1.2cm, % Space from the top margin to the baseline of the header
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{XCharter} % Use the XCharter fonts

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMAND LINE ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Usage:
% \begin{commandline}
%   \begin{verbatim}
%       $ ls
%       
%       Applications    Desktop ...
%   \end{verbatim}
% \end{commandline}

\mdfdefinestyle{commandline}{
    leftmargin=10pt,
    rightmargin=10pt,
    innerleftmargin=15pt,
    middlelinecolor=black!50!white,
    middlelinewidth=2pt,
    frametitlerule=false,
    backgroundcolor=black!5!white,
    frametitle={Command Line},
    frametitlefont={\normalfont\sffamily\color{white}\hspace{-1em}},
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=black!50!white,
    nobreak,
}

% Define a custom environment for command-line snapshots
\newenvironment{commandline}{
    \medskip
    \begin{mdframed}[style=commandline]
}{
    \end{mdframed}
    \medskip
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FILE CONTENTS ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Usage:
% \begin{file}[optional filename, defaults to "File"]
%   File contents, for example, with a listings environment
% \end{file}

\mdfdefinestyle{file}{
    innertopmargin=1.6\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=0.8\baselineskip,
    topline=false, bottomline=false,
    leftline=false, rightline=false,
    leftmargin=2cm,
    rightmargin=2cm,
    singleextra={%
        \draw[fill=black!10!white](P)++(0,-1.2em)rectangle(P-|O);
        \node[anchor=north west]
        at(P-|O){\ttfamily\mdfilename};
        %
        \def\l{3em}
        \draw(O-|P)++(-\l,0)--++(\l,\l)--(P)--(P-|O)--(O)--cycle;
        \draw(O-|P)++(-\l,0)--++(0,\l)--++(\l,0);
    },
    nobreak,
}

% Define a custom environment for file contents
\newenvironment{file}[1][File]{ % Set the default filename to "File"
    \medskip
    \newcommand{\mdfilename}{#1}
    \begin{mdframed}[style=file]
}{
    \end{mdframed}
    \medskip
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NUMBERED QUESTIONS ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Usage:
% \begin{question}[optional title]
%   Question contents
% \end{question}

\mdfdefinestyle{question}{
    innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=0.8\baselineskip,
    roundcorner=5pt,
    nobreak,
    singleextra={%
        \draw(P-|O)node[xshift=1em,anchor=west,fill=white,draw,rounded corners=5pt]{%
        Question \theQuestion\questionTitle};
    },
}

\newcounter{Question} % Stores the current question number that gets iterated with each new question

% Define a custom environment for numbered questions
\newenvironment{question}[1][\unskip]{
    \bigskip
    \stepcounter{Question}
    \newcommand{\questionTitle}{~#1}
    \begin{mdframed}[style=question]
}{
    \end{mdframed}
    \medskip
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WARNING TEXT ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Usage:
% \begin{warn}[optional title, defaults to "Warning:"]
%   Contents
% \end{warn}

\mdfdefinestyle{warning}{
    topline=false, bottomline=false,
    leftline=false, rightline=false,
    nobreak,
    singleextra={%
        \draw(P-|O)++(-0.5em,0)node(tmp1){};
        \draw(P-|O)++(0.5em,0)node(tmp2){};
        \fill[black,rotate around={45:(P-|O)}](tmp1)rectangle(tmp2);
        \node at(P-|O){\color{white}\scriptsize\bf !};
        \draw[very thick](P-|O)++(0,-1em)--(O);%--(O-|P);
    }
}

% Define a custom environment for warning text
\newenvironment{warn}[1][Warning:]{ % Set the default warning to "Warning:"
    \medskip
    \begin{mdframed}[style=warning]
        \noindent{\textbf{#1}}
}{
    \end{mdframed}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INFORMATION ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Usage:
% \begin{info}[optional title, defaults to "Info:"]
%   contents
%   \end{info}

\mdfdefinestyle{info}{%
    topline=false, bottomline=false,
    leftline=false, rightline=false,
    nobreak,
    singleextra={%
        \fill[black](P-|O)circle[radius=0.4em];
        \node at(P-|O){\color{white}\scriptsize\bf i};
        \draw[very thick](P-|O)++(0,-0.8em)--(O);%--(O-|P);
    }
}

% Define a custom environment for information
\newenvironment{info}[1][Info:]{ % Set the default title to "Info:"
    \medskip
    \begin{mdframed}[style=info]
        \noindent{\textbf{#1}}
}{
    \end{mdframed}
}
```

The uploaded code produces the result in figure.
[image]

I'd like to align the left and right text at the same height as the text included into the matrix.
Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide us with a minimal example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}. One reason why I am asking this is because your screen shot does not get reproduced when I compile your code with a preamble `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` at the end. Notice also that very similar questions have been asked and answered here before.

Comment: Unrelated: the code for trigonometric functions is `\sin, \cos`, &c. with a backslash, in order to have them typed with an upright font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `tabstackengnine` package, there are macros that stack things based on a specified baselineskip between rows.  That is what you need here.

I show before (OP code) and after (TABstacks).  However, without your full code (just snippets), I don't get the same misalignment as you with `bmatrix`.

Note that if the vertical extent of some matrices is taller/deeper than others, the TABstack rows will still align---however, the bracket heights may differ (requiring a `\vphantom`).

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
%\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}
\begin{document} 
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:volt_hf_theta_esteemed}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        u_{dh}^{\hat{r}} \\
        u_{qh}^{\hat{r}}
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        j\omega_h \left(L_{avg} + \frac{L_\Delta}{2}cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\right) & j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}sin(2\theta_\epsilon) \\
        j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}sin(2\theta_\epsilon) & j\omega_h \left(L_{avg} - \frac{L_\Delta}{2}cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\right)
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        i_{dsh}^{\hat{r}} \\
        i_{qsh}^{\hat{r}}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
\setstackgap{L}{18pt}
\setstacktabbedgap{6pt}
    \bracketVectorstack{
        u_{dh}^{\hat{r}} \\
        u_{qh}^{\hat{r}}
    }
    =
    \bracketMatrixstack{
        j\omega_h \left(L_{avg} + \frac{L_\Delta}{2}cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\right) & j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}sin(2\theta_\epsilon) \\
        j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}sin(2\theta_\epsilon) & j\omega_h \left(L_{avg} - \frac{L_\Delta}{2}cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\right)
    }
    \bracketVectorstack{
        i_{dsh}^{\hat{r}} \\
        i_{qsh}^{\hat{r}}
    }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the actual packages/template now provided by the OP, while `tabstackengine` aligns the row data, one indeed has to add a `\vphantom` to the vectors to match the bracket sizes.  Note that in this 2-row case, one could argue that the constant baselineskip feature of `tabstackengine` is not necessary since one also has to use the `\vphantom`s.  However, if the matrix is higher than 2 rows, then the use of `tabstackengine` will limit the need of the `\vphantom`s to the top and bottom rows, rather than *each* row of the matrix, as shown in the equation 2 given below.

```
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite} % bibtex

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Lachaise Assignment
% Structure Specification File
% Version 1.0 (26/6/2018)
%
% This template originates from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Authors:
% Marion Lachaise & François Févotte
% Vel (vel@LaTeXTemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,stmaryrd,amssymb,tabstackengine} % Math packages

\usepackage{enumerate} % Custom item numbers for enumerations

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e} % Algorithms

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} % Allows defining custom boxed/framed environments

\usepackage{listings} % File listings, with syntax highlighting
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily, % Typeset listings in monospace font
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DOCUMENT MARGINS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{geometry} % Required for adjusting page dimensions and margins

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Paper size, change to letterpaper for US letter size
    top=2.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=3cm, % Bottom margin
    left=2.5cm, % Left margin
    right=2.5cm, % Right margin
    headheight=14pt, % Header height
    footskip=1.5cm, % Space from the bottom margin to the baseline of the footer
    headsep=1.2cm, % Space from the top margin to the baseline of the header
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{XCharter} % Use the XCharter fonts

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMAND LINE ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Usage:
% \begin{commandline}
%   \begin{verbatim}
%       $ ls
%       
%       Applications    Desktop ...
%   \end{verbatim}
% \end{commandline}

\mdfdefinestyle{commandline}{
    leftmargin=10pt,
    rightmargin=10pt,
    innerleftmargin=15pt,
    middlelinecolor=black!50!white,
    middlelinewidth=2pt,
    frametitlerule=false,
    backgroundcolor=black!5!white,
    frametitle={Command Line},
    frametitlefont={\normalfont\sffamily\color{white}\hspace{-1em}},
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=black!50!white,
    nobreak,
}

% Define a custom environment for command-line snapshots
\newenvironment{commandline}{
    \medskip
    \begin{mdframed}[style=commandline]
}{
    \end{mdframed}
    \medskip
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FILE CONTENTS ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Usage:
% \begin{file}[optional filename, defaults to "File"]
%   File contents, for example, with a listings environment
% \end{file}

\mdfdefinestyle{file}{
    innertopmargin=1.6\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=0.8\baselineskip,
    topline=false, bottomline=false,
    leftline=false, rightline=false,
    leftmargin=2cm,
    rightmargin=2cm,
    singleextra={%
        \draw[fill=black!10!white](P)++(0,-1.2em)rectangle(P-|O);
        \node[anchor=north west]
        at(P-|O){\ttfamily\mdfilename};
        %
        \def\l{3em}
        \draw(O-|P)++(-\l,0)--++(\l,\l)--(P)--(P-|O)--(O)--cycle;
        \draw(O-|P)++(-\l,0)--++(0,\l)--++(\l,0);
    },
    nobreak,
}

% Define a custom environment for file contents
\newenvironment{file}[1][File]{ % Set the default filename to "File"
    \medskip
    \newcommand{\mdfilename}{#1}
    \begin{mdframed}[style=file]
}{
    \end{mdframed}
    \medskip
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NUMBERED QUESTIONS ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Usage:
% \begin{question}[optional title]
%   Question contents
% \end{question}

\mdfdefinestyle{question}{
    innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=0.8\baselineskip,
    roundcorner=5pt,
    nobreak,
    singleextra={%
        \draw(P-|O)node[xshift=1em,anchor=west,fill=white,draw,rounded corners=5pt]{%
        Question \theQuestion\questionTitle};
    },
}

\newcounter{Question} % Stores the current question number that gets iterated with each new question

% Define a custom environment for numbered questions
\newenvironment{question}[1][\unskip]{
    \bigskip
    \stepcounter{Question}
    \newcommand{\questionTitle}{~#1}
    \begin{mdframed}[style=question]
}{
    \end{mdframed}
    \medskip
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WARNING TEXT ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Usage:
% \begin{warn}[optional title, defaults to "Warning:"]
%   Contents
% \end{warn}

\mdfdefinestyle{warning}{
    topline=false, bottomline=false,
    leftline=false, rightline=false,
    nobreak,
    singleextra={%
        \draw(P-|O)++(-0.5em,0)node(tmp1){};
        \draw(P-|O)++(0.5em,0)node(tmp2){};
        \fill[black,rotate around={45:(P-|O)}](tmp1)rectangle(tmp2);
        \node at(P-|O){\color{white}\scriptsize\bf !};
        \draw[very thick](P-|O)++(0,-1em)--(O);%--(O-|P);
    }
}

% Define a custom environment for warning text
\newenvironment{warn}[1][Warning:]{ % Set the default warning to "Warning:"
    \medskip
    \begin{mdframed}[style=warning]
        \noindent{\textbf{#1}}
}{
    \end{mdframed}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INFORMATION ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Usage:
% \begin{info}[optional title, defaults to "Info:"]
%   contents
%   \end{info}

\mdfdefinestyle{info}{%
    topline=false, bottomline=false,
    leftline=false, rightline=false,
    nobreak,
    singleextra={%
        \fill[black](P-|O)circle[radius=0.4em];
        \node at(P-|O){\color{white}\scriptsize\bf i};
        \draw[very thick](P-|O)++(0,-0.8em)--(O);%--(O-|P);
    }
}

% Define a custom environment for information
\newenvironment{info}[1][Info:]{ % Set the default title to "Info:"
    \medskip
    \begin{mdframed}[style=info]
        \noindent{\textbf{#1}}
}{
    \end{mdframed}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ASSIGNMENT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{Problem with matrix alignment}
\author{Not Sure \\ \texttt{not.sure@email.com} \\ Number: \texttt{123456} }
\date{25th-Sep-2018}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Equation (\ref{eqn:volt_hf_theta_esteemed}) is not aligned.

\begin{equation} \label{eqn:volt_hf_theta_esteemed}
\setstackgap{L}{22pt}
    \bracketVectorstack{\vphantom{\Big(}
        u_{dh}^{\hat{r}} \\
        u_{qh}^{\hat{r}}
    \vphantom{\Big)}}
    =
    \bracketMatrixstack{
        j\omega_h \left(L_{avg} + \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\right) & j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\sin(2\theta_\epsilon) \\
        j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\sin(2\theta_\epsilon) & j\omega_h \left(L_{avg} - \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\right)
    }
    \bracketVectorstack{\vphantom{\Big(}
        i_{dsh}^{\hat{r}} \\
        i_{qsh}^{\hat{r}}
    \vphantom{\Big)}}
\end{equation} % fix horiziontal alignment

\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:volt_hf_theta_esteemed}
\setstackgap{L}{30pt}
    \bracketVectorstack{\vphantom{\bigg(}
        u_{dh}^{\hat{r}} \\
        u_{dh}^{\hat{r}} \\
        u_{qh}^{\hat{r}}
    \vphantom{\bigg)}}
    =
    \bracketMatrixstack{
        j\omega_h \left(L_{avg} + \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\right) & j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\sin(2\theta_\epsilon) \\
        j\omega_h \left(L_{avg} + \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\right) & j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\sin(2\theta_\epsilon) \\
        j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\sin(2\theta_\epsilon) & j\omega_h \left(L_{avg} - \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\right)
    }
    \bracketVectorstack{\vphantom{\bigg(}
        i_{dsh}^{\hat{r}} \\
        i_{dsh}^{\hat{r}} \\
        i_{qsh}^{\hat{r}}
    \vphantom{\bigg)}}
\end{equation} % fix horiziontal alignment

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution worked, but as you predicted now I have problems with the brackets. How do I fix this using the \vphantom command? Also I forgot to mention that I downloaded my text structure from a pre-compiled list of templates. The template is https://www.latextemplates.com/template/lachaise-assignment this one.

Comment: @NotSure Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

The `\left` and `\right` provided brackets are too big. The first attempt uses them; the second one uses `\bigl` and `\bigr` instead, which are the best size in this case, but the output is too crowded; finally, the third approach mixes the two.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{With \texttt{\string\arraystretch}}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{bmatrix}
  u_{dh}^{\hat{r}} \\
  u_{qh}^{\hat{r}}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  j\omega_h \left((L_{\mathrm{avg}} + \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\right) 
  &
  j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\sin(2\theta_\epsilon) \\
  j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\sin(2\theta_\epsilon)
  &
  j\omega_h \left(L_{\mathrm{avg}} - \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\right)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  i_{dsh}^{\hat{r}} \\
  i_{qsh}^{\hat{r}}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\section{With \texttt{\string\big}}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
  u_{dh}^{\hat{r}} \\
  u_{qh}^{\hat{r}}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  j\omega_h \bigl((L_{\mathrm{avg}} + \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\bigr) 
  &
  j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\sin(2\theta_\epsilon) \\
  j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\sin(2\theta_\epsilon)
  &
  j\omega_h \bigl(L_{\mathrm{avg}} - \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\bigr)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  i_{dsh}^{\hat{r}} \\
  i_{qsh}^{\hat{r}}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\section{With \texttt{\string\big} \emph{and} \texttt{\string\arraystretch}}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{bmatrix}
  u_{dh}^{\hat{r}} \\
  u_{qh}^{\hat{r}}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  j\omega_h \bigl((L_{\mathrm{avg}} + \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\bigr) 
  &
  j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\sin(2\theta_\epsilon) \\
  j\omega_h \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\sin(2\theta_\epsilon)
  &
  j\omega_h \bigl(L_{\mathrm{avg}} - \frac{L_\Delta}{2}\cos(2\theta_\epsilon)\bigr)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  i_{dsh}^{\hat{r}} \\
  i_{qsh}^{\hat{r}}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]